# Google Cloud Translation API stopped working in TRados

Tags: api, cloud, translation

Google Cloud Translation API stopped working in my SDL trados and in wordfast anywhere.  I get an error message saying the  API key you have entered cannot be validated with Google. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: did you check the API console whether the free limits are reached? are you using a paid version of the API?

Comment: Tharaka, I am using a paid version of the API

Comment: Did you check in the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/billing/) whether your payment details are still valid? I once had a similar problem when a credit card had expired.